# Need to find only three different values in multiple columns then sum using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to find three different values in multiple columns then sum the records that have only these values. If I was looking for the B, D, E, combination, I want to count all records that have this combo. The example below should just return only 2 rows matching the pattern. How would I accomplish this with SQL?

Table:

[image]

Comment: 3 rows have B, D and E in them, but you expect 2 rows?  One row has them in the order of B, D then E.  Could there be a typo? Please edit your example to include rows numbers and indicate which rows you expect to be counted.  Does the order of the columns with the values matter?

Comment: Oh and a suggestion: instead of embedding an image with your data, include it as text so someone that is inclined to help can copy and paste the text instead of having to type it all in :-/

Comment: Gary_W no it is a typo.

Comment: then how do you expect 2 rows when 3 have those values?

Comment: Gary_W. I made a typo mistake when typing out the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that's a little brute force but works with your example test data and specs as known before my questions to your original post have been answered. I bet there's a more elegant regexp_like that can handle it in one where clause test but it's late and it's not coming to me right now. This uses a with clause to build the table as given by the spec.  Then it builds tbl1 which uses tbl and has one column, "joined" which is the data columns from tbl concatenated together. From this it simply gets the count where all of the letters you want are present in the joined column (kind of searching all columns together at once). While maybe not elegant, it is fairly simple and thus easy to understand and maintain.

```
SQL> with tbl(id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7) as (
   select 1, 'D','E','D','E','E','E','B' from dual
   union
   select 2, 'D','B','D','B','B','C','C' from dual
   union
   select 3, 'D','B','D','E','E','B','B' from dual
   union
   select 4, 'D','C','D','B','E','C','A' from dual
   union
   select 5, 'D','C','D','B','B','B','A' from dual
   ),
   tbl1(id, joined) as (
     select id, c1||c2||c3||c4||c5||c6||c7
   from tbl
   )
   select count(*)
   from tbl1
   where joined like '%B%'
   and   joined like '%D%'
   and   joined like '%E%';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         3

SQL>
```

To use with your existing table, do it like this.  Think of the `WITH` clause like creating a virtual or temp table on the fly that will be used by the subsequent query:

```
   with tbl(joined_columns) as (
     select c1||c2||c3||c4||c5||c6||c7
   from your_existing_table
   )
   select count(*)
   from tbl
   where joined_columns like '%B%'
   and   joined_columns like '%D%'
   and   joined_columns like '%E%';
```

Comment: Gary_W thank you. What happens if I have thousands of records to comb through? Is there a way to comb through each row and look for the pattern?

Comment: Thats what this is doing unless I am misunderstanding your question.  I am assuming by sum you mean count by the way,

Comment: I have over 40K rows with values that I need to go through and determine which ones have a certain combo. Is this the best way to do this? Based on this, I would need to code in ever single record. Is there a way to do the union to all the columns that have the values without listing them out?

Comment: Gary_W just wanted to add... Your solution above works exactly as i want it to.  Is there a way to use 'with' clause to run thru the large set of records?

Comment: My "tbl" is just a setup for example purposes.  You would start at the "tbl1" with clause, selecting the columns from your existing table.  I'll edit the example to make this clear.

Comment: I would be interested to see if anyone can come up with a single regular expression to take the place of the 3 `like` calls so a single REGEXP_LIKE() call can be used instead.

Comment: Gary_W. that did it!!! I used it on the data and checked values and it works great!! THANK YOU!!  You are AWESOME. Now one more favor. How do I give you points or credit on this site?

Comment: You are welcome :-)  Just mark the answer as accepted to show future searchers what worked for you.  Using the example above, `select id` and comment out the rest of the line starting with `count(*)`.  The same where clause applies.

Comment: Gary_W I actually got an error:  Here is what I did. I did as you ask and did a select id  from tbl... keeping the same where clause and I get " ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier". Any column from my table will get the same error.

Comment: A select * will return one column named 'joined_column' with the combinations. Can I add additional columns to the With clause to get columns from the my working table?

Comment: Gary_W. Okay, I figured it out. I added the additional columns to the with clause parameter along with the joined_columns 'column' and fix the rest to reflect the change. I now can pull down the names that is associated with the count. Once again thank you very much for all you help.

Comment: Sorry I looked at the wrong example when answering that.  Glad you figured it out.